# Question about cam follower design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, solid-mechanics, machine-design, machine-elements

It's always said that jerk function should be smooth to avoid undesired vibrations. What exactly is the vibration in a cam follower mechanism and why is it important to avoid it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Response of the follower to a cam curve command creates two types of vibrations.

- A steady-state vibration.
- A transient type of vibration.

These vibrations should be designed not to be close to the natural frequency of the camshaft or connecting mechanism.

[source](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/3734499/169394.pdf)

[image: cam jerk]

Answer (score -1):

For car engines, the max rpm can be limited by what is known as valve bounce.

This is where the valve fails to keep up with the cam profile then either hits the cam or cam follower or the valve seat and bounces back.

There have been designs like sleeve valves or desmodromic valves to avoid this but expense comes into the equation.